# defectify or blame or slander?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the verb for saying that this person has a defect? Defectify? Is that standard English? We blame someone of having a defect. Please note that here defect refers to some immoral vice or something that isn't liked in the society.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is such a word as *defectify.*

I would understand a defect to be something wrong with a person that they can't help, like *defective eyesight.* You can't *blame them for* that.

We would *accuse* someone of having a moral failing. To *slander* someone is to say something bad about them that isn't true.

Comment: You can blame someone for giving you defective work, however.  If I ask my mechanic to fix my car, and it comes back defective, that's definitely blame worthy.  I can also blame someone for having defective thinking or defective morals.  If their ideas are defective, it's their fault they haven't fixed it.  But you are of course correct that you can't blame someone for having defective eyesight that need glasses, or defective limbs that can't walk or hold things.